# Gathering Largest and Smallest Numbers in C-String C++

Tags: c++, string, c-strings

my goal for my homework project was to create a program that accepts a series of integers with no spaces in-between as a string. Then to add it up and display the lowest and largest values in the string. I did get my sum and my largest value to work, but for whatever reason, the part of my program that is suppose to get the smallest value is not working, and when I attempt to cout the value, I get nothing.

For example, I enter 1234, I get

"The sum of all numbers within the string you input is 10
The largest value in this series of integers is 4, whilst the smallest value is" ,

Here is my full program. Any help is appreciated (:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
//Declaring Variables & Character Array:
int size = 100;
char integers[size];

//Small and Large Numbers:
char small = '9';
char large = '0';

//Gathering Integers:
cout << "Please enter a series of integers with nothing between them.";
cin >> integers;

//Gathering Size of String:
size = (strlen(integers) + 1);

//Initializing Sum Variable:
int sum = 0;

//Gathering Sum of All Integers in String:
for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
{
    if(integers[i] >= '0' && integers[i] <= '9' && integers[i] != '\0')
    {
        if(integers[i] == '0')
            sum += 0;
        if(integers[i] == '1')
            sum += 1;
        if(integers[i] == '2')
            sum += 2;
        if(integers[i] == '3')
            sum += 3;
        if(integers[i] == '4')
            sum += 4;
        if(integers[i] == '5')
            sum += 5;
        if(integers[i] == '6')
            sum += 6;
        if(integers[i] == '7')
            sum += 7;
        if(integers[i] == '8')
            sum += 8;
        if(integers[i] == '9')
            sum += 9;
    }
}

//Gathering Largest Value:
for(int j = 0; j < size; j++)
{
    if(integers[j] > large)
        large = integers[j];
}

//Gathering Smallest Number
for(int j = 0; j < size; j++)
{
    if(integers[j] < small)
        small = integers[j];
}

//Outputting Values:
cout << "The sum of all numbers within the string you input is " << sum << endl;
cout << "The largest value in this series of integers is " << large << ", whilst the smallest value is " << small << endl;


return 0;
}
```

Comment: It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming. Further reading: [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) and [Debugging Guide](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/)

Comment: Though unrelated to this question, VLAs are not a part of standard C++.

Comment: You might consider converting each character to an unsigned integer value: `uint value = integers[i] - '0';  This allows you to use uint variables throughout the rest of the code.  Here is an example implementation:  https://godbolt.org/z/C3buCL

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The final result of `small` is `\0`, since you' ve scanned the null character, And its value is smallest.

See this: https://ideone.com/6sLWJV

And, as a suggestion. If you guarantee that your input won't surpass the size of the array, stop iteration by judging whether the current character is `\0`, rather than calculating the iteration time and compare it with the size of array.

Comment: Great explanation! I understand it, thank-you so much for your help.

Answer (score 3):

The error is here

```
//Gathering Size of String:
size = (strlen(integers) + 1);
```

This is incorrect, it should be

```
size = strlen(integers);
```

Because you have the size incorrect you are processing the nul character at the end of a string, and this is messing up your smallest calculation (because the nul character is the smallest character).

Comment: Thank-you, you help is very appreciated.